# Want to write an IF condition statement

Tags: syntax, if-statement, esoteric-languages, dog

How to write an `IF` condition syntax in the [DOG](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DOG) language. I don't know how to write an `IF` condition syntax. Any Ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your Wikipedia link:

> Any command can be preceded with a number or variable (dishx, platex,
>   or floor)...But if a plate variable precedes a command, the command is
>   only executed once if the number of cookies on the plate is not 0.

So a plate variable preceding a command acts as an if statement. It is the equivalent of writing something like this in a "real" programming language:

```
if (plate > 0) { do this command }
```

if you want many commands to be conditional on your `if` statement, then you would have to combine it with a `jump` command.

Comment: One doubt is that whether we can use the set brackets as you mentioned above.

Comment: @super, no, I was giving pseudo-code that describes how it will work.  You obviously have to put it in dog syntax.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will follow the syntax.